# Angular 6 router not navigate to first lazy loading module on initial navigation just after login success

Tags: typescript, angular6, router

I couldn't understand why angular router ignoring/skipping the router navigation just after successful login. Behaviour is just like router ignoring first load. I tried timeout also. If need any other code please ping me.
Everything work fine but on first load it is having this error.
Here auth.guard.ts.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
private token;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private tokenId: SessionService
) {
    this.token = this.tokenId.token;
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.token) {
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    return false;
}
```

here is login.component.ts

```
  public async login(data) {
await this.authService.login(data)
  .subscribe((res) => {
    // this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(['/']));
    // this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/']));
    this.router.navigate(['/']);   <======= **this line of code get skipped. I have also tried using async await and setTimeout but nothing works**
  },
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
```

}

also tried this

```
 // login(data) {
 //   let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 //     this.authService.login(data)
 //       .then(async (response) => {
 //         await resolve();
 //         await this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
 //       },
 //         error => {
 //           reject(error);
 //         }
 //       );
 //   });
 //   return promise;
 // }
```

current login method as auth.service.ts

```
public login(data): Observable<any> {
const response = this.http.post(`${localNetwork.apiUrl}/login`, data)
  .pipe(
    map(async res => {
      return res;
    }),
    retry(3),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
return response;
}
    // also tried login using promises
// login(data) {
//   this.loader.loading = true;
//   let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//     this.http.post(`${localNetwork.apiUrl}/login`, data)
//       .toPromise()
//       .then(
//         async res => {
//           resolve();
//         },
//         error => {
//           reject(error);
//           error = this.handleError;
//         }
//       );
//   });
//   return promise;
// }

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ?        `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
return throwError(errMsg);
```

}

I am using angular v6. When user get interact first to application after successful login router does not navigate to lazy loaded module

root router is as follows

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
// loadChildren: () => DashboardModule,   <===== also tried this but it having issue: Error as no compiler option
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
path: 'login',
component: LoginComponent,
},
{
path: '',
redirectTo: '',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }

];
```

Lazy loaded Routing module as dashboard_routing.module.ts

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
 ....... <== other routes here
 ]
 }
 ];
 @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Dashboard module as dashboard.module.ts

```
+imports
 @NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
 ........ <=== other module here
DashboardRoutingModule
   ],
declarations: [
DashboardComponent,
HomeComponent,
],
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

I have also checked related issue in another version also. Waiting for better solution. If required any related query please ping me.

Comment: Could we also see your lazy loaded module? And also the routing module if you have one.

Comment: Last one is Lazy loaded routing module

Comment: I don't think it's lazy loaded module error. Router ignoring first empty path but I have also tried providing "/dashboard" in place of "/" but nothing works. Trying to reorder my module import keeping routing module at last. I don't know whether I am doing right but nothing works

Comment: What is your login method awaiting?  I don’t see a promise in there anywhere.  I’m not sure that would cause this behavior though.

Comment: I have tried both Promises and Observable but nothing works.

Comment: I'm not sure if this accurately reproduces your issue, but I gave an attempt at a similar setup to see if lazy loading works for me and it did. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t94wtj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts Maybe your problem lies somewhere in there. I don't have things like an authentication server, so there was a limit to what I could replicate. I also removed all the async/await and promise related code, because I felt it was unnecessary to use alongside observables.

Comment: @Wingnod I have tried you solution works in serving development mode when I run it in production again getting same issue. Afterward I tried it again in development it again not working. in start it might be due to cached data. I don't know why this weird thing happening here

Comment: Can you change `if (this.token) {` in your auth guard to `if (this.tokenId.token)`? I think the token private member might be initialized before the token is set in certain scenarios. I'm out of ideas as well (since I don't get errors while sync loading). Are you still facing the issue where the `router.navigate` gets skipped?

Comment: I change If(this.token) to if(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) but its not working. Actually I think so whether it's circular changes by storing in global variable and use it as if(this.token) but doesn't works. @Wngnod !  this whole problem happening only when I interact to application first time and if just logout and login with other user then it works. I seems to initially router take it as empty route. Yesterday when I tried your login method I was on normal window. After I open  incognito window and tried but didn't work.

Comment: Actually I am storing token in windows local storage and getting it in authguard. Is there another method to get it directly in if(token). But after storing token login method delay with 1 sec, then is shouldn't behave like this. @Wingnod can you please suggest alter solution for authgaurd? I think this issue commit from this point. May be I am ahead of wrong method doing so by storing token in local storage and then getting it authgaurd.

Comment: Don't copy the login method from my stackblitz if that's what you're doing. Keep your old one, but remove the async in the map. The delay was just there to imitate an http request. Storing your token in local storage and getting it in the auth guard should be fine.

Comment: Yes I do my old method. I get the issue happening. Its all about authgaurd not getting token just after login. Would you please suggest alternative storing token in local storage. Actually my login method getting getting one more issue i.e after success login and token stored in local storage and if reload same route https://example/login then it doesn't navigate to home. Expected behaviour is if already login and user hit http://example.com/login then it should navigate to home automatically.

Comment: @VikasKumar Did you figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem. My lazy loaded module can't be redirected to from a service running at `app.component`. In the route debugger I simply get a `NavigationCancel` without any reason. Loading the module by url or routerLink works fine. Just not `router.navigate` or `router.navigateByUrl` methods.

Comment: @PhyCoMath Yes I was having problem with AuthGuard. My issue is with my method of login not with router (this thing I figure out after many attempts). I'm getting token from other service and in AuthGuard and try to store in global variable 'token' and then checking condition. I have removed all this way. I put it over if  condition as 'if(localStorage.get('token)) {}'. also help to use some better method for login method. I suggest you to just check you login method and AuthGuard. I might be authGuard return false on first check and cancel the router navigation.